# Using network throttling feature for chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I saw that chromedriver released an update which enabled the network throttling feature in the desired capapbilities. I tried but it still uses the same speed on any configuration. See the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


def test_youtube():
    d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    d['networkConnectionEnabled'] = {'type': 'Wifi'}
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path',desired_capabilities=d)
    driver.get('http://www.youtube.com')
    print driver.title
    driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
    driver.quit()
```